# Strange transparency/artifacts when baking normals from a high-poly mesh

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, normals, baking, normal-map

After adding a bunch of details (using KITOPS inserts, mostly) to a high-poly mesh, I've been attempting to bake the details of the mesh to a normal map for a lower-poly version. For some reference, here's a screenshot of the high-poly mesh:
[image: hi-poly mesh]
And here's a screenshot of the low-poly mesh:
[image: low-poly mesh]

This is maybe my fourth or fifth time ever baking textures for 3D models, so excuse me if I use any confusing terms or anything like that, but I've been following some video tutorials and I believe that everything *should* work as I expect it to. When I actually try to bake the normalmap for the low poly mesh, though, I get some very weird results, where some elements (mostly, the KIT OPS assets cutting in to the high-poly) are not correctly present in the baked texture, and are partly (or entirely) transparent, depending on my "Extrusion" settings under the Scene panel > Bake > Selected to Active menu. Here's what the baked texture looks like with Extrusion set to 0.4m, which I understand to be a pretty reasonable extrusion setting:

[image: texture bake 1]
And here's what the output looks like with Extrusion set to 0m:
[image: texture bake 2]
(Note that the transparent elements in the first texture, like the hexagonal "bolt" and the rectangular boolean cutting into the mesh next to that, are partially visible and display that artifacting I'm referring to in the second texture.)

I've tried fine-tuning the Extrusion setting to find a sweet-spot where the bool elements will be visible but not artifacted, but I wasn't able to fix the problem that way. Is this an issue with my meshes? Or is something going on with the renderer?

For the record, I've restarted my Blender, and my computer, multiple times since this issue first began, and nothing has changed.

(My renderer is Cycles (using CPU), and I'm using Blender version 2.93.1, and my OS is MacOS 10.15.7)

Thanks for any help y'all can provide!

Comment: And if you increase Extrusion value? There isn't reasonable Extrusion in general, only for a particular case as it solely depends on scale of the model in the scene. If you aren't lucky in baking with it set to higher value maybe custom cage will be required

Comment: @MrZak, increasing the extrusion value results in outputs similar to the 0.4m Extrusion setting output, where the transparent details remain transparent.

Comment: Make sure normals are pointing correctly (outside) so that object is blue in Face Orientation overlay. Other than that, construct a cage to define custom extrusion value for baking (see online examples for cage, normally duplicate lowpoly)

Comment: @MrZak Gotcha. The transparent areas in the bake occur where I'm using cutters from KIT OPS to boolean cut into the high-poly mesh, so perhaps something about those boolean operations is causing problems with the normals of the faces in the result of the cut.